# Change collision bounds of an object with character physics based on its child mesh in UPBGE

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

I am using character physics on an invisible cube object to control the main character in a game I'm trying to create for my project, but I wanted the character physics objects collision bounds to match my actual character mesh and change according to the current animation.

I tried using compound option but it lead to blender crashes due to exeption access violation or the object would just fall down without colliding with the land mesh

reinstancephysicsmesh() only works with triangulated phy mesh but character physics only support convex hull.

Can someone with a better insight on this please suggest a method to get over this using python or logic bricks(python prefered cause my project requirement asks for python to be used).

Comment: Try asking in the [UPBGE forums](https://upbge.org/#/community) where you're more likely to get an answer. - The game engine was removed from Blender a couple of years ago and this Q&A site deals mainly with native Blender nowadays, albeit still having a game-engine tag available. The docs for it appear to be [here](https://upbge.org/docs/latest/api/index.html).

Comment: i think blenderartists.org is a good/better place to ask for that ;)

Comment: I did ask in blenderartist.com and I am waiting for a reply i asked in this forum too just in case someone who has the knowledge about this appears to pass by the post